# How to place buttons symmetrically?

Tags: c#, winforms

On form I have a `OK button`:

[image]

In code I add `cancel` button and I want to set it symmetrically.

`Ok` button has a `top,left` anchor. `cancel` button - `top, right` button.

And I do:

```
this.CancelButton.Location = new Point(this.OKButton.Location.X ,this.OKButton.Location.Y);
```

But `cancel` button sets closer to center than OK button.

After I do:

```
var leftDash = this.Size.Width - this.OKButton.Location.X - this.CancelButton.Size.Width;
this.CancelButton.Location = new Point(leftDash, this.OKButton.Location.Y);
```

But at all not see `cancel`  button on form.

Any advices?

Comment: A look at the Microsoft Design Guidelines might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511268.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to create `TableLayoutPanel` for controls aligning. In this case you can use panel with two columns.

Or even more simple option (if buttons have same width) - create five columns here:

- Absolute size (left margin, in pixels)
- AutoSize (with button)
- Percent (set 100%)
- AutoSize (with button)
- Absolute size (same amount in pixels)

If buttons have different size, then instead of `AutoSize` columns use columns with absolute size in pixels, which is equal or bigger than biggest of buttons.

Comment: This is a good method that I repeatedly use when designing 2-button dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the Visual Environment of the VS IDE, select both buttons and click on align top icon in the alignment section ribbon of VS IDE

Comment: That will not align button symmetrically to the center